# why my icon has a different behaviour in ios13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

It's been a long time I haven't been working on an ios project.
Anyway, I have an icon that is behaving differently on ios13.

when I change the values, it seems to have an effect on devices running ios 12 and lower but not 13
[image: see image]

```
let showImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: "show-512")!
showHideButton.setImage(showImage, for: UIControlState())
showHideButton.frame = CGRect(x: -10.0, y: 0.0, width: 30.1, height: 22.2)
```

Comment: Mahdi please show the code of `showHideButton`. Your issue is with the offset/inset I think.

Comment: let showHideButton:UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)

Comment: This issue is probably with negative inset/offset. or constraint. I need more to tell the exact issue.

Comment: this is how it was put
txtPassword.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
        txtPassword.rightView = showHideButton

Comment: I add the answer. Let me know if issue has not resolve mahdi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an undefined behavior of iOS 13 about textField's left/right view.

You should manually add **width** `constraint` to the `rightView`/`leftView`.

Don't forget to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

```swift
showHideButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
showHideButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: <#NeededWidth#>).isActive = true
// This is enough to make it act like before but you can set other missing constraints like height to suppress layout warnings and prevent further issues.
// showHideButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: <#HeightOfTheTextField#>).isActive = true
```

You may notice some autolayout warnings in the consule because you didn't set the missing constraint for the `rightView`/`leftView`. So add missing constraints or simply ignore those.

And note that if the `rightView`/`leftView` is some kind of `StackView`, try to putting it inside a `view` and then add this view instead.

### - More Information

From the [iOS & iPadOS 13 Developer Beta 5 Release Notes](http://web.archive.org/web/20190801231842/https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_beta_5_release_notes#3370268):

> UIKit - Resolved Issues
>
> Prior to iOS 13, UITextField assumed that the frames of its leftView and rightView were correctly set when assigned and would never change. Starting in iOS 13, the implementation of leftViewRect(forBounds:) and rightViewRect(forBounds:) now ask the view for its systemLayoutSizeFitting(*:). To achieve the previous behavior when linking against and running on iOS 13, add explicit sizing constraints on the view, wrap it in a plain UIView, or subclass the view and implement systemLayoutSizeFitting(*:). (51787798)